# Align items to the bottom of the container

Tags: html, css

I want to vertically align the items to the bottom of the container. The difficulty is coming from the fact that `.container` is floated left, I didn't find a solution so far.

```css
.container {
  width: 40px;
  height: 250px;
  background: #aaa;
  float: left; /* cannot be removed */
}
.item {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The floated container doesn't affect the items inside I think, I don't know why you emphasize that part.

Comment: I think yes, because `display: table-cell` and `vertical-align: bottom` works, but only without the float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you always have 4 items and everything has a fixed height, you can simply do the math and set some top margin on the first item:

```
.item:first-child {
  margin-top: 90px; /* 250-40x40 */
}
```

You can also use flexbox:

```css
.container {
  width: 40px;
  height: 250px;
  background: #aaa;
  float: left;
  /* new */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
.item {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works great, I just added `flex-shrink: 0` on children.